# What does "practical" mean in this definition?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the definition of *Hint* from [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/hint)

> a small piece of practical information or advice.

Does *practical* above mean [*connected with real situations rather than with ideas or theories*](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/practical)? It seems to me that *practical* above is more likely to mean [*useful or suitable*](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/practical), but OALD says that this definition is used to describe things/objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really interesting question!

It seems like the meaning of *practical* here is a combination of several of the definitions you linked, though I see why none of them seem to fit exactly. If I were to replace the word practical in that sentence, I would say something like:

> A small piece of ***useful/helpful/situationally-relevant*** information or advice.

So that's what it means, but none of the definitions you linked seem to fit perfectly. I went looking and found this other definition on [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/practical), and it seems closer to what you're talking about here:

> **practical**, *adj.*
>
> 4. Capable of or suitable to being used or put into effect; useful: *practical knowledge of Japanese*. See Usage Note at [practicable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/practicable).

And as that usage note is actually quite interesting and useful, I'll include the text here as well:

> **practicably**, *adv.*
>
> ***Usage Note:*** It is easy to confuse *practicable* and *practical* because they look so much alike and overlap in meaning. *Practicable* means "feasible" as well as "usable," and it cannot be applied to persons. *Practical* has at least eight meanings, including the sense "capable of being put into effect, useful," wherein the confusion with *practicable* arises. But there is a subtle distinction between these words that is worth keeping. For the purpose of ordering coffee in a Parisian café, if would be *practical* (that is, useful) to learn some French, but it still might not be *practicable* for someone with a busy schedule and little time to learn.